# Tabla de respuestas con resultados reales

Tags: php, mysql

Puse a hacer un examen a unos estudiantes, tengo un software para que ellos ingresen con su usuario y contraseña, ellos eligen una de 5 respuestas que hay en la página y ya eso se sube a una base de datos.

Las tablas que tengo en la base de datos son: Una que tiene las 5 respuestas, otra que tiene la información de los estudiantes, y otra que relaciona el Id_Estudiante con el Id_Respuesta.

En éste momento ya están votando, pero no me aparecen las respuestas que tengan 0 elecciones. ¿Cómo hago para que me imprima toda la tabla y las respuestas que tengan 0 elecciones?

```
<?php

include 'Conexion.php';

//$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `respuestas` WHERE `Id_Respuesta`= 3 ORDER BY `Id_Relacion` ASC",$con_mysql);
//$cuenta = mysql_num_rows($sql);
//echo $cuenta;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `respuestas` WHERE `Id_Respuesta`= 1 ORDER BY `Id_Relacion` ASC";
$res = mysql_query($sql,$con_mysql);
$row = mysql_num_rows($res);

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `respuestas` WHERE `Id_Respuesta`= 2 ORDER BY `Id_Relacion` ASC";
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1,$con_mysql);
$row1 = mysql_num_rows($res1);

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `respuestas` WHERE `Id_Respuesta`= 3 ORDER BY `Id_Relacion` ASC";
$res2 = mysql_query($sql2,$con_mysql);
$row2 = mysql_num_rows($res2);

$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM `respuestas` WHERE `Id_Respuesta`= 4 ORDER BY `Id_Relacion` ASC";
$res3 = mysql_query($sql3,$con_mysql);
$row3 = mysql_num_rows($res3);

$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM `respuestas` WHERE `Id_Respuesta`= 5 ORDER BY `Id_Relacion` ASC";
$res4 = mysql_query($sql4,$con_mysql);
$row4 = mysql_num_rows($res4);

echo '<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Total de votos</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Candidatos</td>
            <td>Votos</td>
        </tr>';

if(($row = mysql_num_rows($res)) && ($row1 = mysql_num_rows($res1)) && ($row2 = mysql_num_rows($res2)) && ($row3 = mysql_num_rows($res3)) && ($row4 = mysql_num_rows($res4))) 
    {
    echo '<tr>
            <td> Messi </td>
            <td> '.$row.' </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Cristiano Ronaldo </td>
            <td> '.$row1.' </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> David Ospina </td>
            <td> '.$row2.' </td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Arturo Vidal </td>
            <td> '.$row3.' </td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Alexis Sanchez </td>
            <td> '.$row4.' </td></tr>
    </table>';
    }
?>
```

Espero que con ésta poca información me puedan ayudar.

Comment: No entiendo ni la logica del codigo, ni como pueden no aparecer respuestas si el echo muestra todo. a que te referis con eso? y no entiendo ese if, si arriba igualaste las variables a la cantidad de filas, que sentido tiene volver a preguntarlo en el if?

Comment: Es que la tabla sólo se imprime cuando **TODOS** tienen por lo menos una elección, si respondieron todos por una de todas o por 4/5, no muestra la tabla, porque si hay algún campo en 0 no devuelve ningún dato.

Comment: No se entiende bien qué es eso de _las respuestas que tengan cero elecciones_... ¿Existen datos en la bd con ese criterio (_cero elecciones_)? ¿Si existen, no quedan fuera de las consultas a causa del filtro `WHERE Id_Respuesta= ...`? Como dice @gbianchi tu código parece tener un problema de lógica... por ejemplo ¿por qué enviar cinco consultas a la bd en vez de una y evaluar luego el resultado? ¿Por qué usar `SELECT *`... usarás todas las columnas de la tabla?  ¿Por qué usas `mysql_*` que es una función obsoleta?

Comment: Mira @A.Cedano , como anteriormente me ayudaste en que los estudiantes iban respondiendo, eso es lo que necesito empatar, la tabla que me imprima los resultados en tiempo real de los estudiantes que van respondiendo. Lo que estoy haciendo con los llamados es indicar que si la respuesta 1 tiene un número de elecciones, que me lo imprima, pero necesito que me imprima **si hay >= 0**

Comment: Aquí hay bastante gente que te puede ayudar, pero es necesario que plantées con claridad lo que quieres lograr y el problema que estás teniendo para lograrlo. Si no se entiende bien el contexto es difícil dar una respuesta. Además, no sé por qué si en preguntas anteriores usabas la extensión `mysqli` aquí usas `mysql*_`, la cual, aparte de ser obsoleta, hace mucho más difícil la manipulación de los datos, en algunos casos.

Comment: Listo, ¿Qué datos hacen falta para agregar y que quede mejor la pregunta?... Y ya modifico los `mysql_` por `mysqli_`

Comment: Has probado ha repetir la misma consulta pero igualando el Id de respuesta a NULL?

Comment: Para que la pregunta se entienda, deberías explicar brevemente el contexto de tu aplicación, lo que quieres hacer con este fragmento de código, cómo están constituidas las tablas, qué resultado quieres obtener y el problema que estás teniendo. Como comentaba, yo haría una consulta sin `WHERE` y luego en el array de resultados haría las comparaciones, de ese modo nos estaríamos ahorrando 4 consultas a la base de datos.

Comment: Ya lo edité, ojalá funcione.

Comment: no deberias hacer un select Id_Respuesta, count(*) form respuestas group by id_respuesta.. y despues mostrar cada fila de eso??? y para las filas que no vienen nada, podrias mostrar 0 directamente.. me parece que estas complicando un problema simple, tal vez por desconocimiento, lo entiendo.. pero si ademas del codigo explicas la idea y como tienes la tabla, te podemos ayudar mejor...

Comment: @CarlosOrtiz porque no te pasas por el [chat] a ver si podemos solucionar este lio?

Comment: @gbianchi mil gracias, ya me ayudaron en la respuesta de abajo, era sólo poner en el `if($row)` el valor de `>=0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el problema de tu código está precisamente en el if que te comentan en uno de los comentarios, para php el 0 es similar a un false. Cuando haces el if ese con la función para contar filas, en el momento en el que una de las consultas devuelve 0 resultados (y como todas las operaciones lógicas son and) el resultado es un false. Por eso es posible que no te muestre la tabla con los resultados si algún valor es 0.
Una posible solución es mostrar siempre la tabla (quitando el if) o modificando el if de la siguiente manera:

```
if  (($row = mysql_num_rows($res)) >= 0 && ($row1 = mysql_num_rows($res1)) >= 0 && ($row2 = mysql_num_rows($res2)) >= 0 && ($row3 = mysql_num_rows($res3)) >= 0 && ($row4 = mysql_num_rows($res4)) >= 0){...}
```

Comment: Mil gracias, me funcionó.